# Recieving Overpayments in Quickbooks through the Web Connector

Tags: integration, quickbooks, qbwc

I'm the programmer for a company that sells a web-based business software product, that lets the user run their business.  It has an A/R module.  Our users use our software to enter payments from their customers and apply the payments to their customer-invoices in our system.

Our system is also required to sync all financial information to our user's Desktop QuickBoooks.  We use the QB Web Connector to do this.  I have written the code to send a ReceivePaymentAdd to their QB when they enter a payment in our system, and it works well.  The only caveat is when our user's customer sends them an overpayment.

For example, their customer sends them a check for $50.00, but that customer only has an outstanding invoice for $45.00.

The way I'm handling that now is to reduce the check amount to $45.00 and create a credit memo in our system for $5.00.  Then import the $45.00 payment into their QB (applied to the $45.00 invoice), and also import the credit memo for $5.00 (as a credit memo in QB).

We've realized that this approach doesn't work because it throws off their bank account (They have a check for $50.00 in their hands and we've only added a  $45.00 payment to their QB).

I know I can send a ReceivePaymentAdd for the full $50.00, and have only $45.00 applied to invoices.  If I do that, their customer will have a $5.00 credit balance in QB.  And if I remove the code that reduces the payment amount and creates a credit memo in our system, then our system will also record a $5.00 credit for the customer.

I can program our Receive Payment screen to allow our users to apply such customer credits to invoices when entering a new payment, but how do I tell QB to do so?  I see nothing in the **IDN Unified OSR** for that when I look at the ReceivePaymentAdd request.

So to continue the above example, suppose our user informs their customer they have a $5.00 credit, and the user makes a $25.00 purchase and sends a check for $20.00.  Then I will have a ReceivePaymentAdd request with a $20.00 check payment amount, and $25.00 applied to an invoice.  Will this work?  Won't QB throw back an error that the amount applied to invoices is greater than the amount paid?

How do I tell QB (through the Web Connector) to use up the customer credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QuickBooks API works exactly like the UI in this case. So, how would you do it in the UI?

In the UI, you'd ADD a RECEIVED PAYMENT for $50 initially, and apply only $45 of it. That leaves $5 of it unapplied.

Then, when they place the next order you'd ADD a RECEIVED PAYMENT of $20, and apply that to the new invoice. Then you'd go to the original, older received payment and UPDATE (modify) the RECEIVED PAYMENT to apply that remaining $5 to the new invoice.

You'll do the same thing via the API.

Do a `ReceivePaymentMod` on the original payment, and apply the remaining unapplied payment amount to your new invoice.

Comment: `ReceivePaymentMod` requires a field `EditSequence`.  If a payment is added once and not yet modified, is its `EditSequence` 1 or 0?

Comment: Neither. The EditSequence values are unix timestamps for when the record last changed. To do a `Mod` request, you have to first query the record to get the latest EditSequence value, and then use the value you got back from the query in the `Mod` request.

Comment: Intuit doesn't make it easy, does it!  :-)  Thanks.